# Fails to generate Insert,Update,Delete methods on the client-side in ria services

Tags: client-side, wcf-ria-services

I've added insert/update methods to the domain service class.
They start with the appropriate words Insert/Update and are marked with the correspondent attributes.
Yet, they fail to get generated at the client-side so they are unavailable 
from the domain context.
Is it a bug, a known by-design feature, or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods are not exposed on the client side. They are used when SubmitChanges() is called to insert, update and delete entities in the entity collection. You can add and update entities in the entity collection and they will be marked as changed or added. Then when SubmitChanges() is called, your server side code will be used.

I found this article helpful:

[How SubmitChanges works in .NET RIA Servies](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/08/10/how-submitchanges-works-in-net-ria-servies.aspx)